# Android Studio 2.3 CMake doesn't show errors and won't compile C++ code

Tags: android-studio, cmake, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.3, android-native-library

So I'm trying to write my first native library to reuse my C++ code in Android and iOS but just cannot get it to run under Android Studio 2.3

I followed the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle) to the letter (I hope) which mostly consist of:

Write a CMakeLists.txt file containing (in my case):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( 
         test-lib
         STATIC
         src/main/cpp/test.cpp
         src/main/cpp/cpp_wrapper.cpp)

include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/)
find_library( 
          log-lib
          log )

target_link_libraries(test-lib ${log-lib} )

add_library( app-glue
             STATIC
             ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c )

target_link_libraries( test-lib app-glue ${log-lib} )
```

Then link the CMake file to gradle in your modules build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.mysample.id'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.3.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release { ... }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { ... }
}
dependencies { ... }
```

That should be sufficient. Sadly its not. 
I just can't figure out what I'm missing here.
Once (and really only once) I actually got an error message from CMake because of an intentionally placed typo in the cpp file, but that was the only thing I ever saw from it. No library *.so file is created, and of course none is packaged with the apk, so the app crashes as soon as it tries to load it.

Update: I was looking in the wrong place, there actually are some files from CMake in app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake which reflect build configurations and cpu architectures and they even include an `test-lib.dir` directory, but this is empty. I looked through the files to see if there is some clue but couldn't find anything interesting.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a new project, carried out all instructions (again), copied my already existing work over to the new one, voilà.

We'll probably never know what the cause was...